# finding the intersection where multiple 3D parametric equations meet

Tags: matlab, math, octave, intersection

I have some 3D parametric equations that I plot in matlab/octave and would like to find out where they intersect how can I go about doing this. Please note this is just a simple example I plan on having multiple parametric equations that will intersect.

What I'm trying to do is begin and end each plot at an intersection point.

My first thought was putting all the intersection points found at (t) into an array and plotting the ones I want I just couldn't figure out how to get the intersections at (t)

Example matlab/octave code below:

```
clear all, clf
t = 0:pi/60:2.45*pi;
plot3 ((t).*cos(t), (t).*sin(t), (t),'b*'); 
hold on
plot3 ((t).*sin((t)),  (t).*cos((t)),  (t),'r');
```

Here's an image with the arrows pointing to the intersecting points

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that it is better to solve this system of equations analytically if possible.

Look, with your original code (just the plotted line styles were changed)

```
clear all, clf
t = 0:pi/60:2.45*pi;
plot3 ((t).*cos(t), (t).*sin(t), (t),'*b-');
hold on
plot3 ((t).*sin((t)),  (t).*cos((t)),  (t),'or-');
```

I have this picture at one of the intersections:

[image]

Its nice because the two plots intersect perfectly with each other in one of the plotted points.

Now consider the following situation. I changed your second line to

```
t = 0:0.05:2.45*pi;
```

Now I see this at the intersection point:

[image]

Now the two 3D polygonal lines generated for different values of `t` parameter in general case will not have any common points. So simple check for intersection of those linear segments will fail.

Same thing will happed if you update your equations to more complicated ones with more complicated dependencies over `t` (otherwise you are really lucky).
Analytical solution (if possible) will be unbeatable here.

As a numerical way to do this, consider distance D from an arbitrary point P1(x1(t1),y1(t1),z1(t1)) on one line to an arbitrary point P2(x2(t2),y2(t2),z2(t2)) on another one. Then find minimum of D as a function of two independent parameters t1 and t2. If D at minimum is zero (or very close to zero), then these two lines intersect. Otherwise they just pass each other.

Comment: Be careful you don't miss any solutions that way! Maybe you can cummulativly "plot" your functions in a sufficiently granular 3D matrix. At any point with resulting value > 1 you can start your D minimization presented above. It depends on your resources and your requirements :-)

Comment: Forgive me but how would I programming matlab/octave to do this without stopping at the first solution.  Doesn't matlab / octave stop at the first solution found?

Comment: I'll try to illustrate possible algorithm for functions of one variable. In the point where F(x) reaches its minimum, its first derivative is zero and second derivative should be positive (so the function plot near this point is "concave up", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative). This also holds for functions of two variables. You may check for these conditions to estimate how many potential crossing points you have and run more sophisticated algorithm around them.